# angularjs UI grid - assign columns and data dynamically

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I am trying to add columns dynamically to the `ui-grid` and also assigning the data. First time, the grid is working good. But, when i try to change the columns and data dynamically, it is not working as expected.

```
$scope.myfunc = function() {

alert("Rebinding the data");
$scope.gridOptions = {};

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({
 name: 'firstName'
  });
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({
 name: 'lastName'
  });
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({
 name: 'company'
  });
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({
 name: 'employed'
  });

  alert("added new columns");
  $scope.gridOptions.data = data1;

  $scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
};
```

please check the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qtStgClN8heQAc6MI6yG?p=preview)

Can anybody look into this issue and suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think you can remove the code: `$scope.gridOptions = {};`

the latest [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/duN7TA4fPqQpweZc4X5v?p=preview)

the second `data1` should be pushed into the first `data`

I have changed the plunker with the latest code, pls check it!

```
 $scope.myfunc = function()
  {

    alert("Rebinding the data");
     $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = new Array();

    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({
     field: 'firstName'
      });
      $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({
     field: 'lastName'
      });
      $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({
     field: 'company'
      });
      $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({
     field: 'employed'
      });

      alert("added new columns");
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data1;

     /* for(var i=0; i<$scope.gridOptions.data.length; i++){
        $scope.gridOptions.data[i].firstName = data1[i].firstName;
        $scope.gridOptions.data[i].lastName = data1[i].lastName;
        $scope.gridOptions.data[i].company = data1[i].company;
        $scope.gridOptions.data[i].employed = data1[i].employed;
      } */


      $scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
  };
```

if you want to remove the old columns, you would use

`$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = new Array();`

and then refresh data using:

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = data1;

$scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
```

Comment: thanks for the update. but, i want to remove old columns and data once i click on rebind button action. Can you help me on this please?

Comment: i have updated the plunker and the above code, you can use  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = new Array(); and then use $scope.gridOptions.data = data1;

Comment: thank you Vino; it solved my problem of re-assigning / re-binding columns dynamically.